# How to create nested nested reactive forms?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am trying to create a reactive form which will display details on the page about meetings, the labels are dynamic and returned from an API.

Here is a sample of the data returned.

```
const meetings = [
  {
    id: 1,
    date: '06/07/2018',
    meetings: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'meeting 1',
        times: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: '1PM'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: '2PM'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'meeting 2',
        times: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: '3PM'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: '4PM'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: '07/07/2018',
    meetings: [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'meeting 3',
        times: [
          {
            id: 5,
            name: '8PM'
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            name: '9PM'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'meeting 4',
        times: [
          {
            id: 7,
            name: '10PM'
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            name: '11PM'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Here is what I currently have within my HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="formf" novalidate (ngSubmit)="sub()">
  <div *ngFor="let meeting of meetings">{{meeting.date}}
    <div *ngFor="let details of meeting.meetings">{{details.name}}
      <div formArrayName="meetingTime">
        <div *ngFor="let timings of details.times; let i=index">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div formGroupName="{{i}}">
              <label for="selected">{{timings.name}}</label>
              <input formControlName="selected" class="form-control input-sm" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" [disabled]="!formf.valid" value="Save" />
</form>
```

In my component I am creating a form model which is initialised as

```
 initForm() {
    this.formf = this.formBuilder.group({
      meetingTime: new FormArray([])
    });
  }
```

When the data is returned from the API I then try to push it into the FormArray

```
setForm(meetingDate: MeetingDate[]) {
    let meetingTimeArray = <FormArray>this.formf.controls['meetingTime'];
    meetingDate.forEach(date => {
      date.meetings.forEach(app => {
        app.times.forEach(time => {
          meetingTimeArray.push(this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [time.id],
            selected: false
          }))
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

I have the form model printed out on screen and I can see when I click the checkboxes they are only update the first two selected values, I think this is because I have added {{i}} into the formGroupName so they are all mapped to 0, 1 index array.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this working, not sure if it is the most effective way to do it but it works!

Instead of having the index on the *ngFor I have added it into the typescript where I push the controls to the form model.

```
setForm(meetingDate: MeetingDate[]) {
let index = 0;

let meetingsArray = <FormArray>this.formf.controls['meetingTime'];
meetingDate.forEach(date => {
  date.meetings.forEach(app => {
    app.times.forEach(time => {
      meetingsArray.push(this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [time.id],
        selected: false
      }))
      time.index = index;
      index++;
    });
  });
});

this.meetings = meetingDate;
}
```